# Jenkins pipelines trigger one after another

Tags: javascript, java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Can we execute one pipeline from Jenkins and trigger another pipeline with inputdata from previous pipeline? If Yes, will you please provide me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Let’s say there are two pipeline i.e. **jobA** and **jobB**.
Let us assume **jobA** is the upstream pipeline for **jobB** i.e. jobB will be called or build by jobA with parameters (or input parameters from jobA).

Follow the steps below:

1) create both upstream pipeline jobA and downstream piepeline jobB (which will be called by jobA)

2) In **jobB**, Check the box “This project is parameterized” in configure page.

[image]

3) Click on Add Parameter drop-down and select String Parameter.

[image]

4) Fill in the name, default value and description.

[image]

5) Click on Apply and Save.

6) Go to the pipeline **jobA**. Create a stage similar to the stage given below in your Jenkinsfile or Pipeline as a code section.

```
pipeline {
     agent any
     stages {

     stage ('Build JobB')
     {
        steps {
            build job: 'jobB', parameters: [string(name: ‘Environment', value: "production")]
        }
    }
 }
}
```

In this way, you can trigger Jenkins pipeline one after another.

***Note:*** I have use declarative pipeline as code for the example. If you have, scripted pipeline or freestyle project, follow the steps upto step 5 and change the step 6 according to your pipeline.

Comment: understood, Thankyou very much

Comment: Happy to help :)